# Python33 - http.server URL redirecting displaying wrong in the browser

Tags: python, http, url, redirect, request

I am making a python webserver and I am on a part where I want to make my URL's look nice. I don't want to have `www.example.com/index.html`, so I made code that will make the url `www.example.com` redirect to my html file creator, which will return the html code to the browser.

I have another page on my website, which is called `auth.html`, and serves as my login page. Whenever I go from `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/auth`, it works great, but when I click a link to go back to `www.example.com` it will still display `www.example.com/auth` in my browser, even though it is on my index page.

This might not be a big deal, you say, but what if you went on `www.youtube.com` and then to your profile, something like `www.youtube.com/profile/user1231251`, and if you clicked on a link to go back to `www.youtube.com` and it would still display `www.youtube.com/profile/user1231251`. This is very confusing for the user.

in my current request handler I have a few lines of code saying this:

```
if self.path.endswith(""):
    #Make html file, send response and write html file in wfile

if self.path.endswith("auth"):
    #Make auth page, return to browser, etc
```

TLDR:
Going from the `www.example.com/auth` page back to my home page (`www.example.com`), will still display the `www.example.com/auth` link.

Comment: What framework are you using? Does it support checking if a user is authenticated via cookies, request information, etc?

Comment: @KevinLondon I am not using any framework. For a learning project (Not for actual website hosting though) me and a friend decided to make our own webserver, and we are using http.server.